# URLLoader Flash to grab PHP Info

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to send a variable from Flash to PHP, and then echo it back to flash (ignore function names etc. for now; just trying to troubleshoot the basics first).

Flash file (call it test.as):

```
  var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  var file_path:String = "get_this.php";
  var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file_path);
  myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  var memberInfo:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
  myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
  memberInfo.member_id = 10;
  myRequest.data = memberInfo;
  myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
  myLoader.load(myRequest);

  function onXMLLoad(event:Event)
  {
    trace(myLoader.data);
  }
```

PHP file (get_this.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";

$member_id = $_POST['member_id'];   

echo "member_id=$member_id";
?>
```

However, when I do this, the trace on "myLoader.data" returns a massive string consisting of every single word in the entire PHP file, including comments, which are omitted on this post (C++/Flash style comments (//) ), with some random numbers separated by % signs. This surely is an easy fix, but I am rather new to PHP (and not too experienced with Flash yet), so if someone could help me out I would be very appreciative.

Comment: first thing you really don't need that header and xml schema. Next try to acess the php in a browser and check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, test your PHP on the browser and see if its working as expected. Secondly, your complete function should look like this:

```
function onXMLLoad(event:Event)
{
   var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables( event.target.data );
   trace(variables.member_id);
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: How come I have to create a new set of URLVars to grab the data, instead of grabbing the data from the loader itself?

Comment: Also, this may be an extremely mediocre question, but can you test PHP without a server? I am just trying to test a simple PHP script in an html page from my local file path in a browser

Comment: That's just another way of doing it I guess. You can also try myLoader.data.member_id. Basically, event.target is your Loader itself. Also, about PHP, as far as I know, you cannot run it locally without a server. You'll have to either host it somewhere online, or have a local server on your machine. Hope this clarifies :)

Comment: Maybe that is the reason you were getting the entire PHP page as a return in your call, since you are not running it on a server

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote and accepting my answer. Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much! This is another really stupid question, but does PHP have to be downloaded and installed before you can actually attempt to use it as scripts anywhere?

Comment: No problem at all :). From what I know, I don't think you need to download PHP as such. It just needs a server to run on.

Comment: I meant a server that supports PHP.